# Execute windows shell command from java as work in cmd

Tags: java, android, ant, command-line

I want to execute windows shell command from java application.The following task i did in command line to create an android app in windows command line...

```
ANDROID_HOME=E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk
ANDROID_HOME\tools>android create project --target <target id> --name <project name> --     path <project-location-path> --activity <Activity-name> --package <package-name>
```

BUILD THE PROJECT:

```
project-location-path>ant debug
```

It work in windows cmd

Now i want to execute these command from a java application. All required softwares are installed in my computer.

Comment: i use Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); But for some command it return "Access is denied" and other command it throw errors

Comment: The command that you launch cause access is denied, i think is not related with how you launch it. Are you trying to stop a service as users instead as administrator? Are you writing on a restricted folder?

Comment: No, I am try to write that user can write. @FernandoRosado